# Allow off-screen touches with TouchInjection windows 8+ api?

Tags: windows, winapi, touch

I have a situation where I need to embed some 3rd party closed-source Unity applications into our own. I'm injecting a DLL which creates a DX11 shared texture from their swapchain. This part works and it's done.

Additionally I want to hide the form wrapping the Unity app (you can set their parent handle with a command line luckily) so I can have 100% control what happens to its texture in our own app (+ so it wouldn't interfere with the overall look of our own app). Which also works fine, I get the texture without a problem even when the Unity form is completely off-screen.

Now my problem is that this Unity application requires to be used with multitouch and after some fair amount of googling/stack overflow reading I kinda concluded that there's no way (or I haven't found any way) to compose valid `WM_POINTER*` messages just for one window in Windows. (this is kinda supported by the fact that you need to call a separate WinApi function to get all the data of a Pointer/Touch based on their ID which is received in the `lParam` of `WM_POINTER*` message)

So I'm using the TouchInjection Windows API ([InitializeTouchInjection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-initializetouchinjection) and [InjectTouchInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-injecttouchinput)) (information about these API's on the internet are misleading at their best but I solved actually all their quirks) and it works fine if the Unity form is visible on the screen. Or in other words if the touch position is inside the screen boundaries.

And now finally the problem: When I specify an offscreen coordinate for the injected touches, I get an `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87 / 0x57)` system error message. Otherwise it works. Is there a way to turn off this check in windows? Or anybody who solved this problem before some other way?

(Our app is not an end-user one, we have full control over the environment it runs inside, system-wide modifications are also OK.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn off error code checking because it's a return value inside the function, and represents a failure of the function call, then the function return or change nothing but error code. If the error code can be disabled, then what the status of the function call? succeed or fail?
You need to check coordinate manually and detect what to do.

Comment: I don't want to turn off error code checking, I want to enable injected touches which has coordinates outside of screen bounds. Currently we're using a ghost monitor solution but that's not the nicest, a 100% software solution would be preferred.